# angular, setting dynamic tabindex with a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is embarassing.
I can't figure out how to do something appearingly trivial.

```
tr.row(ng-repeat="user in users")
  td
    div(input-inline-edit="user.name" tabindex="{{ $index*10 + 1 }}")
  td
    div(input-inline-edit="user.surname" tabindex="{{ $index*10 + 2 }}")
  td
    div(tabindex="{{ $index*10 + 3 }}")
```

As I have rows, I need to be able to traverse the tabindex by row.
Thus I thought best is to have the first row 1,2,3,4
the next 11,12,13,14
then 21,22,23,24

etc.

I am so embarassed I haven't been able to do this, the above code does not work,
I tried

```
{{$index *10 + 1}}
```

or
`{{getIndex($index, 1)}}")` with in the controller:

```
$scope.getIndex = function(index,i) {
      return index*10 + i;
    }
```

and countless other combinations...I can't believe I haven't achieved to do something seemingly simple

EDIT: OK, turns out I was greedy with info. I have an own directive for inline editing, "input-inline-edit". I have edited the code accordingly above. So if I have that directive, the tabindex does NOT work, but if I have a normal div (the third  in the above example) it DOES!!! So for the first two  I get tabindex=null, for the third I get a valid number. I am baffled.

Comment: THis is strange. I use tabindex="{{ $index*10 + 1 }}"> and works fine...

Comment: div's are tabbable? Can't focus a div

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan you're right! I thought it wouldn't matter, but I have a custom directive. When I use that one, it doesn't work, otherwise it does

Comment: @charlietfl I omitted my custom directive (see edits). The custom directive passes the tabindex on to an internal input element.

Comment: ahhh fair enough...I should have gathered that from attribute `input-inline-edit`

Comment: I guess it's time to setup that plunker already.

Comment: is something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/tgQuZER5kZK5UEqMIlUs?p=preview

Comment: why don't you just give them all the same tabindex? it will nicely go through all of them in order.

Comment: @bokkie will it??? now that is a surprise...I'll try this as soon as I can :) thanks!

Comment: @faboolous I had the same story, I was trying, just like you, to come up with a genius algorithm...until I was told to give them the same tabindex, and guess what...:))

Answer (score 14):

THIS IS EASY.  No need to overcomplicate it.  Simply give each of the repeated elements the SAME tabindex.  Users will still be able to tab through them just as before.